# How to redirect from a CreateView of model A to another CreateView of a model B while passing key information from model A to the next view?

Tags: python, django, redirect, view, model

I am new to Django and do not know what I need to know to do this task. I am tasked with creating a web app that has two models. Model A is the employee and model B is a company that contains many employees. During signup, I have a form for model A. Once model A form is filled out, I need to pass an id from the employee to the company signup url so that when I save the company model to the table, I can make sure that the employee id is stored and so the two tables are related. How do I go about sending the employee_id to the company form page? Do I need to use some sort of redirect?

Flow: dashboard/employee_signup -> dashboard/company_signup -> completed_signup

I've looked through multiple tutorials on Django and most seem to be too simple to solve what I need done.

Here is my EmployeeSignUpView. Right now it redirects to a 'login' page. I need to instead redirect to a CompanySignUpView while passing along an employee_id. A company can't have zero employees, so the first person to signup for the company needs to be stored in the company model. The company table includes a column that stores a list of employees in that company. So a OneToMany relationship.

```
class EmployeeSignUpView(CreateView):
    form_class = FSPEmployeeCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'employee_signup.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of providing a static success_url, you can define `get_success_url` to return a URL that depends on the created object.

Assuming your CompanySignUpView has a URL as follows:

```
path('company_sign_up/<int:employee_id>/', views.CompanySignUpView.as_view(), name='company_sign_up')
```

then you would do:

```
class EmployeeSignUpView(CreateView):
    form_class = FSPEmployeeCreationForm
    template_name = 'employee_signup.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('company_sign_up', kwargs={'employee_id': self.object.id})
```

**Edit**

In your CompanySignUpView you can get the employee ID in the form_valid method:

```
class CompanySignUpView(CreateView):
    ...
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.initial_employee_id = self.kwargs['employee_id'] # or whatever the field name is
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I successfully implemented this, however, how do I go about submitting this employee_id when the company form is submitted. I need to somehow access the company that is about to be created and add the employee_id to the company's employee_list column.

Answer (score 0):

You redirect to something like

```
reverse('b:create_b', kwargs={"pk":a.pk}
```

The URL (in app 'b') is something like

```
url(r'create/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', b_create.as_view(), name='create_b'),
```

And you can pick up this parsed `pk` and convrt it into a full object by subclassing the `dispatch` method in `b_create`:

```
def dispatch( self, request, *a, **kw):
    # resolve kwarg to self.a_object
    self.a_object = get_object_or_404( A_model, pk = self.kwargs.get('pk','?') )
    return super().dispatch( request, *a, **kw)
```

Doing this early means that the rest of your view code can everywhere reference `self.a_object`. It might be more efficient to do this only in `post` or `form_valid`, if it's not needed to (say) generate default values for the initial `get` of the form, or not needed until all the `post`ed data is valid.